# WinEdt (9) keeps reopening previously opened files

Tags: winedt

I'm on Windows 7 with WinEdt 9; I never need/want to use any projects, all I want is to work on one tex file at a time, so when I click on a tex file I want only this file opened by WinEdt. I've used Options Interface Project Manager section (in Application: Projects, Forms, Sounds, ...) to edit the `Project.ini` file, where I've set

```
RESTORE_OPENED_FILES=0
REOPEN_LAST_PROJECT=0
```

and

```
MAINTAIN_PROJECT_LIST=0
```

but this had no effect -- WinEdt keeps reopening all files from the previous session.

In case this is some system-wide `Project.ini`, I've also edited the `Project.ini` file in `\Users\(me)\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 9\ConfigEx\` but this did not help either.

I vaguely remember achieving what I wanted with a previous version of WinEdt after much blind trial-and-error, but I cannot recover in memory what did finally work.

Does anybody know what shall I do?

Comment: See command line switches in the manual.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So the only way is to create a shortcut and run WinEdt from it? I mean, I don't mind to create shortcut but the place in the manual about command line switches is not really easily understandable to me...

Comment: ...besides, all these options in `Project.ini` are there for some purpose, right?

Comment: No it is not the only way, it is one way which I would use as I don't see why you want to disable this for all projects. Beside this: Don't edit the system wide project.ini. Use the user one, and don't forget to reload it (option interface, icon "reload script".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks but would you be so kind to put in an answer what is the command line switch to use my own project.ini, and why is it bad to edit the system-wide project.ini? As for why I want to disable it for all projects - well I don't actually use the project concept at all, I don't have complicated enough setups for that. As WinEdt is on my notebook, I am the only user, so why not tailor it to my needs only?

Comment: winedt can overwrite the system project.ini at updates. Only your user data are safe. Simply doubleclick in the option interface on "project manager",  this will open your user ini, change the ini and then load it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best place where to keep these simple custom changes is the "Private Settings" section of the Option Interface.

To open it, double click on "Private Settings" under "Advanced Configuration" in the Options Interface:

[image]

Just after the line

```
REQUIRES=20111021
```

insert

```
[PROJECT_MANAGER*]
RESTORE_OPENED_FILES=0
```

and then press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file. This will suffice for your requirement.

If you want, you can also add the lines

```
REOPEN_LAST_PROJECT=0
```

or

```
MAINTAIN_PROJECT_LIST=0
```

there, but they are superfluous.

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent answer! Already did it, it does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I have had to ask this from support@winedt.com embarrassingly many times. Recording the procedure here for my own benefit as well :-)

1. Start WinEdt as an administrator (there is a button for this in Options -> Configuration Wizard).
2. Go to Options -> Configuration Wizard again.
3. Select the tab "Filetype Associations".
4. Click "Modify Filetype Associations".
5. There is a box with a caption "Command Switches". Type in "-V ". Without the quotation marks, but observe the trailing space.
6. Click Ok.

Comment: Although I prefer the solution by @karlkoeller this is also good to know - especially considered that without your information I would probably never dream of it. I mean, the command line switches are documented, but how on earth would I figure out that the way to set them is to go to `Modify Filetype Associations`, of all places!?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე That's exactly why I find this difficult. From the point of view of a limited user (like me) that is not a logical place to set a command line switch. I guess that from the programmer's point of view (or from a power user's pov) it **IS** a logical place, because you can (???) then set different command switches to differen filetype associations. Or something like that?