# How to keep previously opened .tex files open while I start winedt

Tags: winedt

I am working on a report and my document class is report. I work with multiple chapters and would like WinEdt reopens all the files from my previous session. Till yesterday it was like that but after clicking new project menu, which was accidental, winedt stopped opening files from my previous session. Please help me to figure this out as I work with more than ten .tex file for my report, and related tasks and opening all these .tex files, from different location, is tedious plus now I lose the continuity of my work.

I use winedt software for writing my report. Whenever I open winedt, it reopens all the files that I was working during the previous session. I need not to open it explicitly, it automatically loads all the .tex files that I was working with from the previous session. Now it is not, and I want to know is there a specific menu or option that can reopen all the .tex files from the previous session.

Comment: Try if you can find the project with `Project -> Open Project`, if not open your files again and then use `Project -> Save Project` to save the state explicitly.

Comment: Thank you @Ulrike Fischer for your help. I tried as per your comment, still it is not working. I guess there should be some option/menu to serve this purpose, i.e., to reload all the .tex files from the previous session. Now, I lost the continuity of my work as I need to open all the files, from my previous session, every single time I open winedt.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408685/managing-the-set-of-files-to-be-opened-when-winedt-starts and look for a -V (virgin mode)

Comment: Thank you very much @Simon Dispa for your help. I tried all those options before posting the issue here. Nothing worked :-(. I dont know why it is behaving so, but quite sure that it must be a simple solution and my bad I am unaware of it.